# forest - Move vertically a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

Here is a basic tree.

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree = {grow' = 0, sn edges},
    [
        [A]
        [B
            [C
                [D]
                [E]]
            [F]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following graphics where I would like the A to be verticaly above the D as indicated by the hand drawn lines. Is there an easy and/or elegant way to do that ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a job for `fit=band`. When you put this option to a node, Forest does not calculate the precise outline of its subtree, but rather puts it in a "band" — the smallest rectangle containing the subtree that extends all the way into the direction of the growth, i.e. it takes the space occupied by the blue line in the OPs picture. See section 3.7.2 of the manual for further information and pictures.

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree = {grow' = 0, sn edges},
    [
        [A, fit = band]
        [B
            [C
                [D]
                [E]]
            [F]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

In this particular case, it might be desirable to adjust the `s sep` of the root node, so that node A does not end up too far north. Remember that `s sep` controls the distance between the outlines of the sibling's subtrees. Above, the outline of subtree A is an "infinite" band stretching past D, so the root's `s sep` effectively controls this distance.

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree = {grow' = 0, sn edges},
    [,s sep=0
        [A, fit = band]
        [B
            [C
                [D]
                [E]]
            [F]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

P.S. To see the distances more clearly, I like to add `draw` inside the `for tree` while working on the tree. Doing so in the second example makes it clear that the north of D and the south of A are aligned and that any remaining vertical distance between A and D is due to `inner ysep` on those nodes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clear answer and the cleanest way to align the node.

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree = {grow' = 0, sn edges},
    [
        [A
            [,no edge] % <---
        ]
        [B
            [C
                [D]
                [E]]
            [F]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sometimes I just need to RFM. :-) Thanks for this !

Answer (score 4):

You can create an additional invisible node with `[,phantom]`

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree = {grow' = 0, sn edges},
    [
        [A][,phantom]%<-- invisible node
        [B
            [C
                [D]
                [E]]
            [F]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks even if I think that is more logical to use `no edge`.